# Vertex paint and image texture combination

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, vertex-paint

I'm trying to have an image as texture and also paint some vertices.
but at the render the result contain some white color on the object.
Any way to avoid this white color from the render and stay only with the painted vertices?

Blend file with the image packed inside.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The default vertex color is white, so that's why you see white everywhere. The traditional way to combine texture & vertex colors is to multiply them: change your Mix node to "Multiply" and set the Factor to 1. That way a white vertex color means "no change to the texture".

Comment: thanks @surest, this is exactly what I have being looking for, it woks perfect..